# How to cumsum the elements of a vector under certain condition in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, conditional-statements, cumsum

My objective is to do a **cumulative sum** of the elements of a vector and assign the result to each element. But when certain condition is reached, then **reset** the cumulative sum.

For example:

```
vector_A <- c(1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1)
```

Now, suppose that the condition to reset the cumulative sum is that the next element has a **different sign**.

Then the desired output is:

```
vector_B <- c(1, 2, -1, -2, -3, 1, -1, -2, 1, -1)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can do `with(rle(vector_A), sequence(lengths) * rep(values, lengths))`.

Comment: Although this does not work when the vector has elements other than -1 and 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R option with `Reduce`

```
> Reduce(function(x, y) ifelse(x * y > 0, x + y, y), vector_A, accumulate = TRUE)
 [1]  1  2 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -2  1 -1
```

or using `ave` + `cumsum`

```
> ave(vector_A, cumsum(c(1, diff(sign(vector_A)) != 0)), FUN = cumsum)
 [1]  1  2 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -2  1 -1
```

Comment: thank you, other's answers also worked and were very good, but this one was the best for me. I'm going to make a small change in the declaration to make it more clear for me: `Reduce(function(x, y) ifelse(sign(x) == sign(y), x + y, y), vector_A, accumulate = TRUE)`

Comment: @JoaquínLoncón yes, thanks. you absolutely can customize it with your recipes :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom function instead of `cumsum` and accumulate results using e.g. `purrr::accumulate`:

```r
library(purrr)
vector_A <- c(1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1)

purrr::accumulate(vector_A, function(a,b) {
  if (sign(a) == sign(b))
    a+b
  else
    b
  })

[1]  1  2 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -2  1 -1
```

or if you want to avoid any branch:

```r
purrr::accumulate(vector_A, function(a,b) { b + a*(sign(a) == sign(b))})

[1]  1  2 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -2  1 -1
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `ave`:

```r
ave(vector_A, data.table::rleid(sign(A)), FUN = cumsum)
#  [1]  1  2 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -2  1 -1
```

---

A formula version of `accumulate`:

```r
purrr::accumulate(vector_A, ~ ifelse(sign(.x) == sign(.y), .x + .y, .y))
#  [1]  1  2 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -2  1 -1
```

Comment: Ah `data.table::rleid()` is nice -- exactly what I was looking for! And really the key to the general problem in this question I think.

Answer (score 3):

The approach that comes to mind is to find the runs (`rle()`) defined by the
condition (`sign()`) in the data, apply `cumsum()` on each run separately
(`tapply()`), and the concatenate back into a vector (`unlist()`). Something
like this:

```r
vector_A <- c(1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1)

run_length <- rle(sign(vector_A))$lengths
run_id <- rep(seq_along(run_length), run_length)

unlist(tapply(vector_A, run_id, cumsum), use.names = FALSE)
#>  [1]  1  2 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -2  1 -1
```

Wrapping the process up a bit, I’d maybe put finding the grouping factor (run
index) in a function? And then the grouped summary will need to be done using
existing tools, like `tapply()` above, or a creative `ave()`, or in the
context of data frames, a `group_by()` and `summarise()` with dplyr.

```r
run_index <- function(x) {
  with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))
}

ave(vector_A, run_index(sign(vector_A)), FUN = cumsum)
#>  [1]  1  2 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -2  1 -1
```

Comment: nice use of rle!